# compare 2 arrays of objects of different length

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-modules

I have this array of objects

```
var test = [{
    jobId: 1,
    requiredNumber: 1,
    actualReq: 1,
  },{
    jobId: 2,
    requiredNumber: 1,
    actualReq: 1,
  },{
    jobId: 3,
    requiredNumber: 1,
    actualReq: 1,
  },{
    jobId: 4,
    requiredNumber: 1,
    actualReq: 1,
  }]
```

and this array of objects

```
var testArr = [{ jobId: 1, current: 1 },
 { jobId: 2, current: 1 },
 { jobId: 4, current: 1 }]
```

I want to compare these arrays and return a flag if jobId is missing from the 2nd array like `jobId 3` or if the `current` of `jobId` is smaller than `actualReq` from the 1st array

what I have done is making nested loops for each array and compare but it didn't work for me

```
var y = false;
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < testArr.length; j++) {
    if (test[i].jobId === testArr[j].jobId) {
      if (test[i].actualReq <= testArr[j].current) {
        y = false
      } else {
        y =true
      }
    } else {
      y = true;
    }
  }
}
console.log(y);
```

it always returns true

Comment: The logic is flawed. It is recommended to (1) write it as a function, (2) return false (hence early exit) at the first sign of falsehood, (3) fully execute all your loops and if no falsehood is found, finally exit on true.  The way how you have written, any falsehood can be subsequently overwritten by truthness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner solution to your problem statement using. I have not updated the logic of yours

```
test.forEach(value=>  console.log(testArr.some(item => value.jobId === item.jobId && value.actualReq <= item.current)) )
```

if you want the list of objects with true/false values you can use the `filter` method

`true` :

```
 test.filter(value=>  testArr.some(item => value.jobId === item.jobId && value.actualReq <= item.current) )
```

`false` :

```
 test.filter(value=>  !testArr.some(item => value.jobId === item.jobId && value.actualReq <= item.current) )
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to break from the loop when you find the one which is `true`

```js
var test = [{
  jobId: 1,
  requiredNumber: 1,
  actualReq: 1,
}, {
  jobId: 2,
  requiredNumber: 1,
  actualReq: 1,
}, {
  jobId: 3,
  requiredNumber: 1,
  actualReq: 1,
}, {
  jobId: 4,
  requiredNumber: 1,
  actualReq: 1,
}]
var testArr = [{
    jobId: 1,
    current: 1
  },
  {
    jobId: 2,
    current: 1
  },
  {
    jobId: 4,
    current: 1
  }
]

var y = false;
main:
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < testArr.length; j++) {
    if (test[i].jobId === testArr[j].jobId) {
      if (test[i].actualReq <= testArr[j].current) {
        y = false
      } else {
        y = true
        break main
      }
    } else {
      y = true;
      break
    }
  }
}
console.log(y);
```

I would use `every` or `some` instead

```js
const test = [{
  jobId: 1,
  requiredNumber: 1,
  actualReq: 1,
}, {
  jobId: 2,
  requiredNumber: 1,
  actualReq: 1,
}, {
  jobId: 3,
  requiredNumber: 1,
  actualReq: 1,
}, {
  jobId: 4,
  requiredNumber: 1,
  actualReq: 1,
}]

const testArr = [{
    jobId: 1,
    current: 1
  },
  {
    jobId: 2,
    current: 1
  },
  {
    jobId: 4,
    current: 1
  }
]

const result = test.every(job => {
  const other = testArr.find(j => job.jobId === j.jobId)
  if (!other) return false
  return job.actualReq <= other.current
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with one loop, looping over the first array. You can then use [Array.Find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to see if the job ID exists in the second array. If not, you can return (or do whatever you want) and then compare the second objective, the `actualReq` vs the `current`.

```js
var test = [{
    jobId: 1,
    requiredNumber: 1,
    actualReq: 1,
  },{
    jobId: 2,
    requiredNumber: 1,
    actualReq: 1,
  },{
    jobId: 3,
    requiredNumber: 1,
    actualReq: 1,
  },{
    jobId: 4,
    requiredNumber: 1,
    actualReq: 2,
  }]
  
var testArr = [{ jobId: 1, current: 1 },
 { jobId: 2, current: 1 },
 { jobId: 4, current: 1 }]
 
test.forEach((t) => {
  const matching = testArr.find((ta) => ta.jobId === t.jobId)
  // The jobId is missing, log it and return it
  if (!matching) {
    console.log(t.jobId, 'is missing')
    return t.jobId
  } 
  
  if (matching.current < t.actualReq) {
    console.log(`Job ID: ${matching.jobId} -`, matching.current, 'is less than', t.actualReq)
  } 
})
```